# Data truncated in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table and insert some data but I am getting an error:

> Data truncated for column 'days' at row 1

The data is truncated from column days. I have kept the data type as DATE.

```
CREATE TABLE Reserves (
    sid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    bid INT, 
    days date
);

INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,101,'10/10/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,102,'10/10/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,103,'10/8/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,104,'10/7/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(31,102,'11/10/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(31,103,'11/6/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(31,103,'11/6/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(31,104,'11/12/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(64,101,'9/5/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(64,102,'9/8/98');
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(74,103,'9/8/98');
```

Comment: There is no Column called `days` in the table you describe? Or the INSERT commands you show us

Comment: I don't understand your question, i don't see any 'days' column here. Maybe can we have the right code ?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong code. I have made the edit.

Comment: _Small Point_ Storing a Base 12 number in a decimal is an interesting choice! It would be more useful to store their Date Of Birth then you could work out there age Today and Tommorrow and Next Year when you actually want to see it

Comment: Mysql Date format for a DATE DataType is always `yyyy-mm-dd` again if you want to see it in a specific locale format you should convert it in the presentation layer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Technically you are correct, but you can still add the date as `dd-mm-yyyy`, its just that MySQL converts it back to `yyyy-mm-dd` before storing it in the database

Comment: @KebabProgrammer Yes, so then you are using MySQL as part of your presentation layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting a wrong date format, you should do :

```
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,101,'1998-08-10');
```

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,103,'10/8/98');
```

That's why MySQL truncate your data because he can't guesses all of the date format.

DATE format : `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: I'm really surprised. You can find this in the MySQL documentation : `The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.`. So I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/peUFt5k4miZUnxBVXeZs9u/0 You can take a look here, it's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change your insert to:

```
INSERT INTO Reserves(sid,bid,days) VALUES(22,101, STR_TO_DATE('10/10/98', '%d/%m/%Y') );
```